# use a R hist function with data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

I have a doubt about the function hist() in R when using columns of a data frame as variables of the function.
Later I expose it in the most concrete way.
I have the following data frame:

```
    Var1    frec
1   78.0    1
2   81.0    4
3   84.0    2
4   87.0    3
5   90.0    2
6   92.0    4
```

I would like to use the values of the column “Var1” as values of the axis X from the historiograma, and that the values that are in the column “Freq” would be the ones that define the height of its bars. Another detail more that I would like to have, is that in the axis X it  would go out as label “Tag-Phase”, and that in the axis Y it would appear “Number of Tags”.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: In this case you want to produce barplot instead of histogram. Histogram is for presenting continuous data in intervals (eg. see Scott intervals for building histograms). Barplot is for presenting nominal or ordinal data. So in this case if you want to present aggregated data - use barplot, otherwise use histogram.

Answer (score 4):

```
barplot(dat$frec, names.arg = dat$Var1, xlab = "Tag-Phase", ylab = "Number of Tags")
```

[image]

Comment: Now I understand, at first believed that only they could do with hist (), thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Alex feel free to mark this as the selected answer if it worked for you